# How can I remove or delete a specified part of a file name at a certain range of columns?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

For instance say I have `file1_6363`, `file1_6364` and `file1_6365`. I simply want to remove the first 63 as you can see there's another 63 in the first example and so far I've been using this PowerShell command :

`get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("63", "") }`

But as you can see I don't know how to specify the column at which I want the 63 to be removed and so it deletes any 63 combination that it detects.

(If possible I would like to have solutions using PowerShell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to offer another option with more flexibility, the [`-Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator can match regular expressions and [use capture groups in the replacement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#regular-expressions-substitutions). Capture groups in regular expressions are defined by being enclosed in parentheses and referenced in the replacement string with the syntax `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

If the sole criteria for selection is positional, the regex can be constructed using the `.` wildcard and, optionally, various [quantifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#quantifiers) to specify the number of characters to match:

> | Quantifier | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `*` | Zero or more times. |
> | `+` | One or more times. |
> | `?` | Zero or one time. |
> | `{n,m}` | At least `n`, but no more than `m` times. |

You can explicitly specify each wildcard or use quantifiers, as the following are equivalent and could be used interchangeably:

| Count | Explicit | Quantifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `'.'` | `'.{1}'` |
| 2 | `'..'` | `'.{2}'` |
| 3 | `'...'` | `'.{3}'` |
| 4 | `'....'` | `'.{4}'` |
| 5 | `'.....'` | `'.{5}'` |
| 6 | `'......'` | `'.{6}'` |
| Etc. | Etc. | Etc. |

So for your example, the `-NewName` scriptblock would be:

- `{ $_.Name -Replace ( '(.{6})(..)(.*$)' , '$1$3' ) }`

  - | Group | Syntax | Captures |
    | --- | --- | --- |
    | 1 | `(.{6})` | First six characters |
    | 2 | `(..)` | Next two characters |
    | 3 | `(.*$)` | Remaining text to end-of-line |
- The replacement string, `'$1$3'`, concatenates capture groups 1 and 3, thus eliminating capture group 2 (columns 7 and 8).

But if the initial portion of the name is variable in length, for example:

- file1_6363
- file12_6364
- file123_6365

You could instead define the first capture group to be variable in length, capturing everything up to and including the underscore (`_`):

- `{ $_.Name -Replace ( '(.+_)(..)(.*$)' , '$1$3' ) }`

  - Capture group 1 now captures one or more characters (`.+`) until the underscore is matched.

As an aside, regardless of your method of string manipulation, the `-Path` parameter of the [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) cmdlet can take pipline input, eliminating the need for `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 |
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace ( '(.{6})(..)(.*$)' , '$1$3' ) }
```

Additional References:

- [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: so then say I want to keep the first three characters and then remove the next three and keep the rest , the -Newname scriptblock would then be : { $_.name -replace ( ' (.{3} ) ( ... ) ( . *$)' , '$1$3' ) } correct ? ( I'm new to PowerShell btw and in serious need of guidance )

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But this particuar question is about regular expression syntax, so take a look at the link to the cheat sheet -- I use it all the time. But in short, `'.{5}'` is equivalent to `'.....'` and `'..'` is eqivalent to `'.{2}'`, etc. It's just a matter of preference and/or less typing...   :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your files names have always the same length, you can rename them by removing char at index 5 and 6 :

```
get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item "$_" "$($_.Name.Substring(0,5))$($_.Name.Substring(7))" }
```

The code replace the name of each file by a new name created with the first 5 chars of the old name concatenate to the char of the old name starting at index 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for the first [index of](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) `_` and then [remove](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-6.0) 2 chars from there. So it would work with any filename with an underscore.

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Remove($_.Name.IndexOf('_') + 1, 2)}
```

Example:

```
PS C:\Users> gci -name
abc_6363.txt
abcde_6364.txt
abcdefg_6365.txt
PS C:\Users> gci | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Remove($_.Name.IndexOf('_') + 1, 2)}
PS C:\Users> gci -name
abc_63.txt
abcde_64.txt
abcdefg_65.txt
```